# link to the other website in "the_title()" of the WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have the single-portfolio.php which present one of my project.

This function makes proper title to my projects every time I choose one.

```
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Now whatever project i choose it always transport me to the Angela...

```
        <h1><a href="https://twitter.com/angela_bradley"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

What i want to do is to have proper link to the proper project in the title.

I figured sth like this but it does not work.

```
      <?php 
        $f = "http://facebook.com/";
        $t = "http://twitter.com/";
        $l = "http://linkedin.com/";

        if (the_title()=='Facebook') {
         Echo "<a href=$f> Facebook</a>";
        } elseif (the_title()=='Twitter') {
         Echo "<a href=$t> Twitter</a>";
        } else {
         Echo "<a href=$l> Linkedin</a>";
        }
         ?>
```

What i get on the page is 3 times written Facebook if its Facebook page or 3 times Twitter e.g:

FacebookFacebookFacebook(the only last one "Facebook" is a link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `the_title()` echos the title, rather than returning it (as documented in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)). That means that, for each of your `if` conditions, the title gets echoed out.

Try using [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead - this returns the post title rather than echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

the_title() is a function that returns the title of the current page/post in wordpress. For the FB/Twitter/LinkedIn portion of your code you should just include "Facebook" instead of using the_title()

Comment: Thanks for a answer but it didn't help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom field in your post to store the link in the post. Call the field "url" for example:

[image: WordPress custom field]

now you can read the field in your template and use it:

```
<?php $url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "url", true ); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new but it won't help me because I'am not using post's but new pages. This option goes only with new posts

Comment: @userlooser This works for pages as well. If you don't see the "Custom Fields" section in your edit page screen you can enable it by clicking on "Screen Options" on the top right.